# How to seed has_many/belongs_to associate?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have two models:

- connector (connector.rb)
- connectors_data (connectors_data.rb)

Their respective db tables are:

- connectors
- connectors_data

`connectors` may have many `connectors_data` and the latter belongs to a `connector`. The field `connector_id` connects the two tables together with a foreign key.

I can't workout how to seed the db so that a `connector_data` row can be created. Right now, my `seeds.db` file creates `connectors` just fine but doesn't create any `connectors_data`

### connector.rb

```rb
class Connector < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :connectors_data
end
```

### connectors_data.rb

```rb
class ConnectorsData < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :connectors
end
```

### seeds.rb

```rb
require 'faker'

10.times do
  con = Connector.create(
    user_id: 1,
    name: Faker::Company.name,
    description: Faker::Company.buzzword
  )
  con.connectors_data.create!(
    version: Faker::Number.number(digits: 5),
    comment: Faker::Lorem.sentence
  )
end
```

### inflections.rb

```rb
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections(:en) do |inflect|
  inflect.irregular 'data', 'data'
end
```

### Error message

When running `bin/rails db:seed` I get the following error message:

```sh
rails aborted!
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Connectors must exist
/Users/n00b/Code/Ruby/MyProject/db/seeds.rb:16:in `block in <main>'
/Users/n00b/Code/Ruby/MyProject/db/seeds.rb:10:in `times'
/Users/n00b/Code/Ruby/MyProject/db/seeds.rb:10:in `<main>'
/Users/n00b/Code/Ruby/MyProject/bin/rails:5:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/n00b/Code/Ruby/MyProject/bin/spring:10:in `block in <top (required)>'
/Users/n00b/Code/Ruby/MyProject/bin/spring:7:in `<top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => db:seed
```

Comment: Can you please change `create` to `create!` to get a proper error message?

Comment: Have added the error message

Comment: That means that the creation of the connector in the `con = Connector.create` line failed. Can you please replace the `create` in that line with `create!` to see why the connector was not created? I guess a validation failed or there is no user with an id of `1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was to edit `connectors_data.rb` to be:

```rb
class ConnectorsData < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :connector
end
```

and **not**:

```rb
class ConnectorsData < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :connectors
end
```